# How to have a request scoped variable in remix JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, remix.run

I'm new to remix Js and wanted to understand what the best way is to get this done.

I have an app that calls a function which in turn calls an API to load user details. This user information is used to paint multiple things like header, footer and load the appropriate view for the user.

The thing I notice is that currently for a single page load request from the browser, the function (and in turn the API) is called independently multiple times by the module that renders the header, footer, page etc. What I wanted to know is if it is possible to have the user details saved in a variable so that for a single request all the modules can use this variable and it needs to be only fetched once per browser request.

I tried the following but it did not work

```
let userDetails;

export function getUserDetails(userId){

  if(!userDetails){ 
     console.log("Calling API to fetch user details);
     //call the API
     userDetails = async getUserById(userId);
  }
  return userDetails;
}
```

One option we have is to save the user details in the browser/session but that is not allowed due to some policies. What would be the best way to achieve this so that we only need to call the API once per request from the browser and save subsequent calls for a single page load to fetch the same info ?

TLDR : what would be the best way to initialize an object in an remix server module so that its value could be accessible by other modules and it has to be set only once per a request from a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dataloader](https://github.com/graphql/dataloader) can be used to solve this issue.

It offers request-level caching (and batching) which means parallel loaders on the initial HTML request can cooperate while remaining independent.

Example usage with remix can be [found here](https://github.com/remix-run/examples/tree/main/dataloader).

```js
// Root.tsx
export const loader = async ({ context }) => {
  const user = await context.loaders.userById.get("user_1");
  return json({ user });
}

// ...

// Child.tsx
export const loader = async ({ context }) => {
  // This will await the same promise created in the Root.tsx loader
  const user = await context.loaders.userById.get("user_1");
  return json({ user });
}

// ...
```

Having said that, I would warn that the abstraction cost of dataloader is quite high and to only use it if you really can't afford to call into your API multiple times (loaders run in parallel so it's more an issue of upstream load over performance).

It's also worth noting that SPA navigations won't see the benefit because each loader is called as a separate request from the browser so a request-level cache will be ineffective.