# Remix run: How to pass prop data from a parent component to the loader/action function of child components?

Tags: reactjs, remix.run

Using Remix run, is it possible to pass prop data from a parent component inside the loader/action function of child components?..
If not does anyone know of a method to get parent data inside the loader/action functions of child components?
Many thanks,
J

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Remix, loaders are run in parallel, so there isn't a way to pass data from a parent loader to a child loader. This is to prevent fetch waterfalls and improve performance.

Once the data is fetched, you can access it from your UI components. Use `useMatches` or `useRouteLoaderData` to get data from another route loader.

> NOTE: they are working on adding *middleware* support so that you can have a function called before and after your loaders. You then pass that data via `context` to your loaders.

Comment: Thanks @kiliman.. so if I have a use case where in my main component I get an access token from an external api there’s no way to pass that on to the child components that will need it in their loader and action functions?

Comment: Probs not the best use case as I imagine sessions could be used -  but there’s no way without sessions?

Comment: @jon that's right. It's important not to have loaders depend on one another because for SPA navigations they are called independently from one another as separate requests. If upstream load on DBs / APIs is a problem, you could potentially use dataloader https://stackoverflow.com/a/75296564/607471